# c3.js area chart: area opacity disappears after a line is selected

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I created an area chart and want the keep the opacity 1.0 of the area under the line, but when I select a line, the opacity goes away and stays away for all the lines too. I'm wondering how I can keep the opacity for the areas under the lines no natter what?

I've tried doing mouseover/ mouseout but that doesn't do exactly what I want it to all the time, because I have to pause a little bit over the legend for the mouseout to work. I did this by creating a new legend, and here is code for that. I've tried a lot of other simpler things, and tried to code in refreshing the data, but this is the closest I got to following this site:
https://c3js.org/samples/legend_custom.html

```
//this part is the new legend part, but can be added after the foundation part. 
//or it may be omitted too. 
    function toggle(id) {
        chart.toggle(id);
    }

    d3.select('.container').insert('div', '.chart').attr('class', 'legend').selectAll('span')
        .data(['data1', 'data2', 'data3'])
      .enter().append('span')
        .attr('data-id', function (id) { return id; })
        .html(function (id) { return id; })
        .each(function (id) {
            d3.select(this).style('background-color', chart.color(id));
        })
        .on('mouseover', function (id) {
            chart.focus(id);
            //chart.flush();
            d3.selectAll(".c3-area").style("opacity", "1.0");
        })
        .on('mouseout', function (id) {
            chart.revert();
            //chart.flush();
            d3.selectAll(".c3-area").style("opacity", "1.0");
        })
        .on('click', function (id) {
            chart.toggle(id);
            d3.selectAll(".c3-area").style("opacity", "1.0");
        });


//this part is the foundation
    var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['data1', 300, 350, 300, 0, 0, 0],
                ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50],
                ['data3', 100, 200, 0, 300, 350, 220]
            ],
            types: {
                data1: 'area',
                data2: 'area-spline',
                data3: 'area'
            } 
        }
    });
    d3.selectAll(".c3-area").style("opacity", "1.0");
```

I expected for the opacity to stay 1.0, which it does, until I click on the selection tool on the bottom and then the opacity resets back to something like 0.3, or whatever the default is. There are no error messages for me.

I also tried this and it doesn't work:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 300, 350, 300, 0, 0, 0],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'area',
            data2: 'area-spline'
        },
        style: {
            opacity: 1.0
        },
        legend: {
            item: {
                onclick: function (id) {
                    //d3.selectAll(".c3-area").style("opacity", 1.0);
                    chart.load();
                    d3.selectAll(".c3-area").style("opacity", 1.0);
                    //chart.load();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `onrendered` function in the config may be what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/9t24cz8q/

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#areachart",
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 300, 350, 300, 0, 0, 0],
      ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
    ],
    types: {
      data1: 'area-spline',
      data2: 'area-spline'
    }
  },
  onrendered: function () {
    d3.selectAll(".c3-area").style("opacity",1);
  }
});
```

Here, the opacity of the series area moused over in the legend is set to 1, and the others return to 1 afterwards.